Discrepancy in answer to a question about vectors
The components of a vector along the $x$ and $y$ directions are $(n+1)$ and $1$ respectively. If the co-ordinate system is rotated by an angle $60^\circ$, then the components changes to $n$ and $3$. The value of $n$ will be what?
While answering this question if we use the fact that the length of the vector is invariant we get,
$$\sqrt{(n+1)^2+1} = \sqrt{n^2 + 9}$$
$$\implies n = 7/2
 = 3.5 $$
But when we just calculate the components directly in each coordinate system (assuming that the coordinate system is rotated anti-clockwise) we get the answer to be $1+\sqrt{3}$.
In the initial coordinate system, the vector is :
$\vec a$ = (n+1)$\vec i$ + $\vec j$ , where $\vec i$ and $\vec j$ are unit vectors in the x and y directions respectively.
In the new coordinate system let $\vec x$ be the unit vector instead of $\vec i$ and $\vec y$ be the unit vector instead of $\vec j$.
$\vec i$ = $\cos(60)$ $\vec x$ - $\sin(60)$ $\vec y$
$\vec j$ = $\sin(60)$ $\vec x$ + $\cos(60)$ $\vec y$.
Substituting these values in the expression for
$\vec a$ we get,
$\vec a$ = (n+1) ($\cos(60)$ $\vec x$ - $\sin(60)$ $\vec y$) +  $\sin(60)$ $\vec x$ + $\cos(60)$ $\vec y$.
$\vec a$ = ((n+1) $\cos(60)$ + $\sin(60)$)$\vec x$  + ($\cos(60)$-(n+1)$\sin(60)$)$\vec y$
Equating (n+1) $\cos(60)$ + $\sin(60)$ to n we get ,
n-n$\cos(60)$= $\cos(60)$+$\sin(60)$= (1+$\sqrt3$)/2
n(1-1/2)= (1+$\sqrt3$)/2
Therefore n = 1 + $\sqrt 3$.
So which one is correct and why?

First attempt seems correct, maybe if you provided details about the second it could be verified what went wrong. By the way, here is how to format maths at this website: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

For me the correct answer is: those conditions are impossible. In other words: there is no such value of $n$.
Let's follow your second attempt, but I will use matrix notation for rotating a vector by angle $\theta = -60^\circ$ (we rotate coordinate system by $60^\circ$ so the vector is rotated by $-60^\circ$). Let's $\vec{v} = \langle n + 1, 1\rangle$ and $\vec{v_r}$ to be rotated vector. Now we have:
$$
v_r= \left[
\begin{matrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
n + 1  \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right] = 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
(n + 1)\cos(-60^\circ) -  \sin(-60^\circ)\\
(n + 1)\sin(-60^\circ) + \cos(-60^\circ)
\end{matrix}
\right]
= 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\frac{n+1}{2} +  \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}(n+1) + \frac{1}{2}
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
But now, if we compare components of our $\vec{v_r}$ to given vector $\langle n, 3 \rangle$, we will get:
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{n+1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = n \\
-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(n+1) + \frac{1}{2} = 3
\end{cases}
$$
But you can check, that this system of equations does not have a solution (and it wouldn't have even if we rotated coordinate system by an angle $-60^\circ$ - you can check it).

The first approach tells you, when those vectors $\langle n + 1, 1\rangle$ and  $\langle n, 3 \rangle$ have the same lenght. However we showed, that it is impossible for them to form an angle of $60^\circ$.

Never mind ; I think it looks ok :) I was just thinking that if the "coordinate system" was rotated something weird would happen.

Ok, I noticed that I was working with rotation of vectors not, coorditanate system... But it still works when we change $\theta \to -\theta$

Yes that was my doubt ; but I think as you say it still works with your method.

I have fixed my solution

Thank you so much
